# Configuring independent widgets (Tkinter ttk, Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, ttk

I'm fairly new to programming in general so apologies for any stupidity.

I've made this program with python and Tkinter, for calculating capacitors in electronics for different units. The program is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        valuex=int(x.get())
        valuey=int(y.get())
        valuez=int(z.get())
        cappf.set(int(str(valuex)+str(valuey))*10**valuez)
        capnf.set(int(str(valuex)+str(valuey))*10**valuez*10**-3)
        capuf.set(int(str(valuex)+str(valuey))*10**valuez*10**-6)
    except ValueError:
        pass

root=Tk()
root.title('Capacitor Calculator')
mainframe=ttk.Frame(root, padding='10 10 10 10')
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

x=StringVar()
x_entry=ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=3, textvariable=x)
x_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W,E))
y=StringVar()
y_entry=ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=3, textvariable=y)
y_entry.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W,E))
z=StringVar()
z_entry=ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=3, textvariable=z)
z_entry.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=(W,E))
cappf=StringVar()
capnf=StringVar()
capuf=StringVar()

ttk.Button(mainframe, width=7, text='Calculate', command=calculate).grid(column=2, row=5, sticky=(N, E, W, S))
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=cappf).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=capnf).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=capuf).grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Input:').grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Amount:').grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Units:').grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='pf').grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='nf').grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='uf').grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=N)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text='Quit', command=root.destroy).grid(column=2, row=6, sticky=(N, E, S, W))

ttk.Style().configure('TLabel', padding=6, font='Corbel 16', foreground='#0077AF')
ttk.Style().configure("TButton", padding=6, relief="flat", font='Corbel 18', foreground='#00AA11')

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=3)
x_entry.focus()
y_entry.focus()
z_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', calculate)

root.mainloop()
```

Running it in the Py 3.4.0 shell, it works fine as it is.

My question is: What do I do/how do it make it so that the 'quit' button displays red font? Right now, the 'ttk.Style()' section near the bottom effects all buttons to configure them in the same way; i've looked online but I can't find a solution that works, or at least that i'm applying properly.

Thanks,

Zach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Create a new [`tkinter.ttk.Style`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style) for the button that has its `foreground` option set to red.
2. Assign the button's [`style`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#standard-options) option to this style.

Below is a fixed version of your script:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        valuex=int(x.get())
        valuey=int(y.get())
        valuez=int(z.get())
        cappf.set(int(str(valuex)+str(valuey))*10**valuez)
        capnf.set(int(str(valuex)+str(valuey))*10**valuez*10**-3)
        capuf.set(int(str(valuex)+str(valuey))*10**valuez*10**-6)
    except ValueError:
        pass

root=Tk()
root.title('Capacitor Calculator')
mainframe=ttk.Frame(root, padding='10 10 10 10')
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

x=StringVar()
x_entry=ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=3, textvariable=x)
x_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W,E))
y=StringVar()
y_entry=ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=3, textvariable=y)
y_entry.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W,E))
z=StringVar()
z_entry=ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=3, textvariable=z)
z_entry.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=(W,E))
cappf=StringVar()
capnf=StringVar()
capuf=StringVar()

ttk.Button(mainframe, width=7, text='Calculate', command=calculate).grid(column=2, row=5, sticky=(N, E, W, S))
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=cappf).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=capnf).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=capuf).grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Input:').grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Amount:').grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Units:').grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='pf').grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='nf').grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='uf').grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=N)
##########################################################################################################################
ttk.Button(mainframe, text='Quit', style='red.TButton', command=root.destroy).grid(column=2, row=6, sticky=(N, E, S, W))

ttk.Style().configure('red.TButton', foreground='red', padding=6, font='Corbel 16')
##########################################################################################################################
ttk.Style().configure('TLabel', padding=6, font='Corbel 16', foreground='#0077AF')
ttk.Style().configure("TButton", padding=6, relief="flat", font='Corbel 18', foreground='#00AA11')

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=3)
x_entry.focus()
y_entry.focus()
z_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', calculate)

root.mainloop()
```

The stuff I changed is in the comment box.

Comment: Thanks! That really helps, now that I can see how it works , which is really helping me get to grips with programming.